# How to evaluate a simple C# string

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

I have been reading up Expression trees, and I think this is a good example to use them, still I can't seem to grasp how this would be done.

I have a set of strings that I want evaluated, they are all of the type:

```
exp == exp , or exp != exp , or exp (<,>,>=,<=) exp if exp is Numerical Type.
```

The exp do not need to check if they are valid I am fine with them blowing up if they are not.

My issue is, how to I parse to get the actual obj.

I want to pass a string like these below

```
Owner.Property.Field == 3;

or

Owner.Field == 3;

or 

Owner.Method(1) == true
```

And get if the evaluation is true or not. MY issue is how do I travel down the "path" on the left and get the value?

I implemented a version with Reflection and string parsing, that somehow does the work - except for when we are using a method, and honestly its not that performant at all. I want this to be as performant as possible can get, and if possible give me a small explanation of how the expression works , so I can  learn.

Comment: if you want us to explain *your* code to you, then maybe you should post it first

Comment: No, I have my uses reflection and string parsing, I actually want a way to do this via Expressions. I will edit for clarification

Comment: no matter what - post what you tried so far - if you did try nothing and want us to do your work you are out of luck (with me) anyway

Comment: You got me wrong, I am not trying to get work done, I actually wanted to gete a explanation on how expression trees work, since I have now realized my conception of expression trees were completly wrong.
Somehow I had the idea that a expression tree could somehow parse a string and evaluate it, without much work on my side. I feel a big dummy right now, that I somehow understand it.

I am working on something currently, and I will post what I come up with.

Comment: @Carsten , there what I currently have worked out in the last 30 mins or so, I scrapped the reflection one I made, and its going somewhat well, except for method calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use code generation libraries like `CodeDOM` or `Roslyn` to generate  Func that will do the evaluation.

For example, in `Roslyn` you can create a `Session` and set an object containing `Owner` as the `Host object` of the `Session`. than you can generate the code in the `Session` as you wish like the following:

```
Session session = ScriptEngine.CreateSession(objectContainingOwnerAsProperty);
bool result = session.Execute<bool>("Owner.Field == 8");
```

Now `result` will contain the evaluation result for your string without `reflection` nor string analysis.

Comment: Unfortunely I can't use Roslyn :( But this would work in any other case, I guess

Comment: CodeDom is possible, but I have really no idea how that works. Any hints on how this would be possible?

Comment: Istead of host object, generate a `RuntimeAssembly` with a class containing the method you wish, only also with a property of the type of `Owner`. than create an instance of that class with `Activator.CreateInstance()`, fill than property and invoke.

Comment: Yeah I figure it out, thats why I marked it as answer ! =)

Comment: Great, If you're having trouble feel free to ask.